# Issue with relinking a dropbox account

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I have a simple free app which I am trying to allow users of the application to backup their data to **Dropbox** for safe keeping.

This all works just fine until I unlink the account and then relink the account.  Then my next call fails.

Here is the calls that are made:

```
- (IBAction)linkToDropBox:(id)sender {
    if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
    }
    [self checkForBackups];
}

- (void) checkForBackups {
    //Determine if backup exists
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];
    }
}
```

The first time this is execute it works with no issues, however when I first unlink by calling `[[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];` and then call link toDropBox the linking is successful, the loadMetada fails.

```
2014-03-26 13:01:24.065 appName[3519:60b] App linked successfully!

2014-03-26 13:01:24.626 appName[3519:60b] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/metadata/sandbox - (403) Parameter not found: oauth_token

2014-03-26 13:01:24.628 appName[3519:60b] Error loading metadata: Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error 403.)" UserInfo=0xb900290 {path=/, error=Parameter not found: oauth_token}
```

If I then close my view and open it again, it works.  Seems that for some reason the call needs the view to reload?

I am unsure as to what is happening here?  Any help on direction to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably because you're still using the old restClient after unlinking/relinking. You should clear and recreate the restClient. More info: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=94511

Comment: Thanks - I actually tried that and it didn't make a difference.  I'll try again - just in case I didn't do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a simple one.

I needed to move these calls:

```
self.restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
self.restClient.delegate = self;
```

From -(void)viewDidLoad to -(void)viewDidAppear

Since the restClient was set only on the creation of the view, it never was reset.

Thanks Greg - this helped!